# Logging out automaticly after 1. time login

Tags: php, html, css, authentication

I have a problem. If i log in to my website as user at 1time and click for example to settings or profile button(i am trying to create social website) it logs out automaticly. but if i try to log in 2. time it logs in and works without any problem. This problem comes back if i clear browser data. Is the problem on session? or cookie? there is log in code:

```
function user_id_from_username($username){
$username = sanitize($username);
return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id');
}
function login($username, $password){
$user_id = user_id_from_username($username);

$username = sanitize($username);
$password = md5($password);

return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'"),0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
}
```

there is sanatize function:

```
function sanitize($data){
return htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($data)));
}
```

Comment: It was a final addition to `mysql*` functions before they were **deprecated** that anyone using them would have this problem (jk). Look at learning / upgrading to a supported database API such as PDO.

Comment: There isn't any code here that stores a user to a session or a cookie...

Comment: lols sorry I need to point out again, that first comment was a terrible joke (not the learning PDO part, that is a good idea)

Comment: i anderstand ;) But where can a problem be? why at 1. time it not works but 2. time it works good? I have seen some codes, that saves session to storage. what do you thing can it help? @DavidBarker

Comment: It sounds like a cookie problem tbh. Usually you have to set a cookie and then reload for that cookie to have an affect, it seems that you set the cookie on the page load after login is complete. Could you see if you refresh browser cache, login, wait for load, hit page refresh and then start navigating. I bet that would not require you to have to login a second time.

Comment: thank you for help. I will try to create function to save cookie and in future i will update to PDO. :)